# Borrar URL al recargar

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo un login, me salió todo perfecto con PHP, solo que tengo un problema. Cuando no se encuentra un usuario en la base de datos, PHP regresa lo siguiente:

```
header("Location: ../index.php?error=userNotFound");
```

Ese parámetro lo capturo con un GET de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['error']))
{
  if($_GET['error']=="userNotFound")
  {
?>
<div class="alert alert-danger fade in">
  <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
    <strong>Acceso denegado.<br/></strong> El usuario y/o la contraseña no existe.
</div>
<?php }}?>
```

El problema viene que cuando recargo la página con <kbd>F5</kbd> o le doy <kbd>Enter</kbd> a la URL:

```
?error=userNotFound
```

No se borra, eso provoca que vuelva a aparecer el `alert` y tengo que borrarlo manualmente.

¿Me podrían decir una forma de limpiar el URL cuando se recargue la página?

Comment: Estás trabajando con GET, no es posible lo que planteas a menos que utilices cookies o la sesión.

Comment: Y como hago eso, la sesión se crea justamente al pasar ese formulario, al igual que la cookie, pero si no pasa el Login, no habrá ni cookie ni sesión. ¿Habrá otra forma de hacer eso?

Comment: Claro que sí puede haber cookie y claro que sí puede haber sesión, no necesariamente se necesita un login para eso, si no entonces no podrías mantener la información del shopping cart en cualquier tienda en línea sin iniciar sesión (login).

Comment: Ok, ya hice la sesión sin que pase por el login
session_start();
$_SESSION['LOGGED'] = 'FALSE';
Ahora cómo hago para que desaparezca lo de la URL?

Comment: De hecho no deberías pasarlo por la URL, deberías poner un valor en la sesión y en index.php lees la sesión para ver si está o no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como menciona [Shaz en los comentarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/19674/borrar-url-al-recargar#comment31456_19674), puedes usar sesiones para eso. La idea sería la siguiente:

1. En la página donde si no se encuentra un usuario se redirecciona al index con el mensaje de error debes: 1) Iniciar sesión al principio; y 2) antes de hacer la redirección, guardar una variable de sesión con el error.

   El código sería algo como esto:

   ```
   // inicia sesión
   session_start();

   // ... cálculos y resto de página ...

   // guarda la variable de error y redirecciona
   $_SESSION["error"] = "userNotFound";
   header("Location: ../index.php");
   ```
2. En la página de inicio (index): 1) comprobarías si esa variable de sesión está instanciada; y si lo está (similar a como ya lo haces ahora), 2) muestra el mensaje de error y borra la variable (de este modo no se mostrará  cuando se recargue la página con F5).

   El código sería algo como esto:

   ```
   // inicia sesión
   session_start();

   // ... cálculos y resto de página ...

   // si exista la variable de sesión de error
   if(isset($_SESSION['error']) && $_SESSION['error']=="userNotFound")
   {
        // borra la variable y muestra el mensaje de error
        unset($_SESSION["error"]);
   ?>
   <div class="alert alert-danger fade in">
      <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
      <strong>Acceso denegado.<br/></strong> El usuario y/o la contraseña no existe.
   </div>
   <?php 
   }

   // ... cálculos y resto de página ...
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Teniendo en cuenta que Alvaro ya explicó en la práctica lo que [comenté rápidamente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/19674/borrar-url-al-recargar#comment31466_19674) en cuanto a la sesión, voy a mostrar el método por medio de cookies, solo como una alternativa (yo usaría el método de sesión, el cual también de cierta forma se apoya en cookies):

En el archivo donde se procesa el login, digamos **login.php**:

```
...
// asumiendo que la variable contenga un boolean con el resultado de la autenticación
if ($login) { 

    // login exitoso ...

} else {
    setcookie("loginError", 1, time() + 120); // 2 minutos de vida debería ser suficiente
    header("Location: ../index.php');
}
```

Luego, en el archivo **index.php** verificamos si existe la cookie y mostramos (o no) el mensaje de error:

```
...
if (isset($_COOKIE["loginError"]) && $_COOKIE["loginError"]) {

    // si existe, hacemos que expire (en 1 segundo)
    setcookie("loginError", false, 1);
    ?>
    <div class="alert alert-danger fade in">
      <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
      <strong>Acceso denegado.<br/></strong> El usuario y/o la contraseña no existe.
    </div>

<?php } ?>
...
```

Insisto, esto es solo un método alternativo, crear una cookie con una "vida" tan corta es poco útil en la mayoría de los casos.